# always show link in list from typeahead from bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

this is a code I found here http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/typehead.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />  
    <title>Bootstrap typehead example by w3resource</title>  
    <link href="http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
</head>  
<body>  
<div class="well">  
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='["Ahmedabad","Akola","Asansol","Aurangabad","Bangaluru","Baroda","Belgaon","Berhumpur","Calicut","Chennai","Chapra","Cherapunji"]'>  
</div>  
<script src="http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>  
<script src="http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>  
</body>  
</html> ​
```

It's working but I want to add a small feature in it. I want to create a link in the list that will always show up at the bottom of the list. So if you type something if will filter the list but a link in the bottom will always show up.

Comment: Please set up a fiddle so we can play with it.

Comment: I cant get it to work in jsfiddle but it works if you save the codes locally. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chanckjh/8qZd8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is just to extend typehead prototype to redefine its render method:

```
var uber = {render: $.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.render};
$.extend($.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype, {
    render: function(items) {
        uber.render.call(this, items);
        this.$menu.append('<li class="nostyle"><a href="#" onclick="alert(123)">some link</a></li>')
        return this;
    }
});​
```

See this demo http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/8qZd8/2/

Comment: Thank you. After some finetuning in my own codes I got it to work.